# how to display cards on the same line using display flex?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to display cards on the same line and use flex-wrap: wrap to wrap. But it's not working, what's wrong with my code?

**Code**

return(

```
<div className='container-poster'>
        <div className='poster'>
            <div className='poster-img'>
                <img src={poster} />
                <i>
                    {isFavorite ?
                        <FaHeart className='heart-icon' style={{ color: 'red' }} /> : <FaHeart className='heart-icon' style={{ color: '#BABABA' }} />
                    }
                </i>
            </div>
            <div className='poster-title-vote'>
                <h4 className='title-movie'>
                    {title}
                </h4>
                <div className='box-note'>
                    <span className='rating'>{rating}</span>
                    <i className='icon-vote-like'>
                        <img src={IconLike} alt="icon like"></img>
                    </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p className='overview'>
                {overview}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

)

**Reality**
[image]

*I want it to be a maximum of 4 cards in the same row and then break it when there's no space*

SandBox

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-waterfall-10s5gx?file=/src/Poster.js

Comment: To begin, you need to separate the logic and styles from the html structure.

Comment: Your SandBox doesn't work.

Comment: `display: flex` by default places child elements in one line. `flex-wrap: wrap` is added only when you need to move items to another row if their total width is greater than the width of the parent element.

Comment: Did not help. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add `display: flex;` on your parent `.container-poster`. This will make all elements nested in each flex-item `.poster` row item. You can then use `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column` on your `.poster` to get the title underneath.

See below:

```css
.container-poster {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.poster {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100%/4.1); /* .1 for spacing */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-poster'>
  <div class='poster'>
    <div class='poster-img'>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class='poster-title-vote'>
      <h4 class='title-movie'>Title
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class='box-note'>
      <span class='rating'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='poster'>
    <div class='poster-img'>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class='poster-title-vote'>
      <h4 class='title-movie'>Title
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class='box-note'>
      <span class='rating'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='poster'>
    <div class='poster-img'>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class='poster-title-vote'>
      <h4 class='title-movie'>Title
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class='box-note'>
      <span class='rating'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='poster'>
    <div class='poster-img'>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class='poster-title-vote'>
      <h4 class='title-movie'>Title
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class='box-note'>
      <span class='rating'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```